# I used xib to load the inputView in my custom keyboard. I Would like to know how to change height of inputView when orientation changes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, custom-keyboard

i have been developing a custom keyboard with extensions. i would like to change the height of the keyboard when the device rotates. Currently am not using sizes classes just the autolayout constraints. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you given the Hight constraints to your keyboard view?

Comment: yes i have tried to add height constraints  to the inputView but its not working. could you please let me know when to change the constraint's constant. i mean in which call back?

Comment: do you know how to change the Constraints height programmatically?

Comment: yes i know to change the constraints height programaticaly

Answer (score 0):

When you rotate your device for example portrait to landscape right and Landscap right to portrait.

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    if (fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        // change you height constraints here when landscap;
    }
    else if (fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait)
    {
        // change you height constraints here when portrait;
    }
}
```